# What are the "must reads" online for learning the ins and outs of multithreading?

Tags: multithreading

Over the last couple months I've been working with programs that involve multi-threading aspects to them. Multi-threaded programs a very new to me and while I understand the crude basics, how to go about designing a multi-threaded program is still beyond my skill-set. I would like to know what resources that people have found online that gave you an "Omg! That makes total sense now!" moment for this topic.

This should probably be a community wiki but due to the latest changes to SO, I can't make it one (that I know of at least).

Edit: I'm aiming toward reading that is language-independent if possible. Though I don't want to discurage anything that might be particular of a language if it is informative enough to general multi-threading program design.

Comment: What are your languages of choice? If you haven't any then check out Erlang.

Comment: Am I crazy or is there a quip that goes something like "anyone who thinks they understand multithreading is wrong"?

Comment: @Peter, you're not crazy :) !

Comment: @Peter I never pretend I *know* multi-threading. I know of the concept and crude basics of what multi-threading *is*. What I have issues with is how to go about trying to design a multi-threaded application (or even just a package which makes use of multi-threading). When I attempt to make something with multi-threading involved, it feels like when I first started programming and I never had a good design up front. I was just smashing letters on the keyboard and making sure it all compiled and seemed to run properly, but this doesn't seem like how it *should* be done.

Comment: I wasn't trying to diminish your efforts to learn more about threading.  Just trying to add a little humor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Herb Sutter has a Dr. Dobbs column called [Effective Concurrency](http://herbsutter.com/2010/09/24/effective-concurrency-know-when-to-use-an-active-object-instead-of-a-mutex/) that's terrific. It's a little C++-centric but the underlying lessons are well explained and are bite-sized so you don't get overwhelmed.

Answer (score 1):

### Threading must-reads

- The [Threads FAQ](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/threads-faq/), by Bryan O'Sullivan (hacker extraordinaire)
- [The Problem with Threads](http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/publications/papers/06/problemwithThreads/), by Edward A. Lee (on how and why non-deterministic multi-threading is so difficult)

### Concurrency must-reads

- [The Free Lunch Is Over](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/concurrency-ddj.htm), by Herb Sutter (on the pragmatic importance of concurrency)
- [The C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html), by Dan Kegel (if you plan to do any large-scale network programming)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some basic starting points:

I don't want to state the obvious, but there's the Wikipedia article: [Wikipedia: Multithreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading)
There's also a relatively old Linux article here: [Multithreading and Linux](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1363)
  and a POSIX threads tutorial: [POSIX threads tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html)
For Windows, here's a great MSDN article: [What Every Dev Must Know About Multithreaded Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163744.aspx)

If you want to go get some decent cross-platform multithreading books, there are:

- [Threads Primer: A Guide to Multithreaded Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134436989)
- [Modern Multithreading : Implementing, Testing, and Debugging Multithreaded Java and C++/Pthreads/Win32 Programs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471725048)
- [Porgramming POSIX Threads](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633922)

Answer (score 0):

I see you have been active in C/C++ tags here.  In that case [the Boost.Thread documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread.html) might be interesting. This provides portable implementations of important threading concepts and states clearly how to use them. If I was starting out as a C++ multithreading programmer, I would absolutely not build this stuff myself but use this library. The author of the library (active on Stack Overflow under his real name) has [a book coming out soon](http://www.manning.com/williams/), which appears to be available online now for a fee.